# Why has my bath tap gotten stuck/stripped loose twice?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures, cartridge

Bathroom about 5 years old, thermostatic valve on bath filler. Twice now the valve has gotten impossible to turn, like it’s gritted up inside somehow. I replaced the cartridge before but this seems like I might need to replace the whole filler unit? I can’t think of what could be wrong with it that would make this keep happening though, it can’t be filled with grit yet taking ~1 year to mess up the cartridge, can it?

Comment: Not sure from your post what's gritting up, the volume control or the thermoststic control. If it's the thermostatic valve it usually happens because it typically is only rotated in a very short range and mineral deposits build up. It's a good idea to rotate the control from stop to stop on a regular basis to break up calcium deposits before they become too heavy. You also could remove the cartridge and soak it in a decalcifying agent - even vinegar will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not grit but calcium deposits that collect in the mechanism.